# Throwing NullPointerException while changing pointers

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, linked-list

I have to implement a `undo()` method in a LinkedList class. Everytime if any element is added by `add()` that element is pushed into `undoStack`. Right now, I have 6 elements and the code is throwing a `NullPointerException` from this line:

```
object.prev.next = object.next;
```

Can someone tell me how to fix this problem?

```
protected Node<T> beginMarker;  // Dummy node marking the front of the list
protected Node<T> endMarker;    // Dummy node marking the back of the list

//beginMarker and endMarker are already initialized!

public void undo() {
        if(undoStack.isEmpty()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Undo history is empty");
        } else {
            Node<T> object = undoStack.topAndPop();
            redoStack.push(object);

            if(object == beginMarker) {
                beginMarker = beginMarker.next;
            } else {
                object.prev.next = object.next; 
            }
            if(object == endMarker) {
                endMarker = object.prev;
            } else {
                object.next.prev = object.prev;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: It's too little code to debug, are you perhaps not setting `prev` or `next` properties correctly when adding objects?

Comment: Debug to see what's `null`. I'm betting my money on `object.prev`.

Comment: My guess is that you run into the case where object was the last element, so object.next is `null`

Comment: @hotzst Why would calling object.next throw a `NullPointerException` if `object.next` is null but `object` isn't?

Comment: @Manu you are right, on that line either `object` or `object.prev` is null.

Comment: Think about your code inside `if(object == beginMarker)` and `if(object == endMarker)`. If these are supposed to be dummy nodes, why do you support removing them? That implies that after removing all nodes, `beginMarker` and `endMarker` become `null`.

Comment: @Holger, I still don't get what you mean by that. Could clarify more?

Comment: the line `beginMarker = beginMarker.next` overwrites `beginMarker` and when its `next` value is `null`, then you obviously are on the road to the `NullPointerException`. Since, according to your comment, `beginMarker` is supposed to be a “Dummy node marking the front of the list”, it’s not clear why you ever overwrite it. After overwriting it, it isn’t a “Dummy node marking the front of the list” anymore. Same applies to the `endMarker`.

Comment: @Holger, so every other node should be removed/added between beginMarker and endMaker, not including beginMarker and endMarker?

Comment: That’s what I assume according to your comment, but since it’s your code, you should know how it’s supposed to work…

Comment: @Holger, thanks for the reply! One last question: when I `pop()` a Node from stack, how does it know that it should be inserted back into its old position? I've been overthinking this process for so long. Does a Node also save its next and prev pointers in stack or what?